# Why does `include_once` successfully serves the html while `readfile` fails in php?

Tags: php, html

I have the following function

```
public function my_index()
{

    try {
        define("PATH_ROOT", dirname(__FILE__));
        var_dump(PATH_ROOT);
        include_once PATH_ROOT . "/test.php";
        //readfile('./test.php');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }

    die;

}
```

Inside my `test.php` I have

```
<div>This is test</div>
```

I verify that `test.php` is in the same directory as the file that host `my_index`

But whenever I try

```
readfile('./test.php);
```

It always return

```
readfile(./test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

and when I comment `readfile` out, it actually is able to serve the content of `test.php`

Can someone explain why `include_once` is serving the html? Is this the idiomatic way to serve html in php?

Comment: Because the file does not exist in the current directory. When using `include_once` you prepend the `PATH_ROOT` constant, which gives you a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

You gave absolute path for include_once.

```
 include_once PATH_ROOT . "/test.php";
```

Try same for another.

```
readfile(PATH_ROOT . "/test.php");
```

Note:
You can check the current working directory with [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)